# How can I change the font weight of this string? (Screenshot attached)

Tags: css

I want to change the font weight of the String **"Willkommen im B2B Shop"**, but dont know why it remains the same:

https://b2b.schneider-sportswear.de/schneiderb2btest/Anmeldung

I am a complete newbie to CSS and I am thankful for any advice where to look or what to do.

I tried to edit the element via element.style and it baffles me that nothing happens.

[screenshot of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdkvS.jpg)

Comment: the font face you used there mapped to `Uni Sans SemiBold` has only 2 "weights". But actually there's a difference betweeen `font-weight: 400`and `font-weight: 600`. Isn't it enough? did you need a bolder font?

Comment: That's because you've imported only one weight for the font. So only that weight is available for you to use.

Comment: Thank you very much... yes, I need many different weights in fact all over the website. Our customer sent us only one and our 2 Front-End developers are drowning in work. They pushed this task to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using 'Uni Sans SemiBold' font family and this gives you the font weight of 600 only, you need to use more variants i.e. 'Uni Sans Bold' for font weight greater than 600 (i.e. bold).

```
font-weight: 300; -> light
font-weight: 400; -> normal(regular)
font-weight: 500; -> medium
font-weight: 600; -> semi-bold (your font)
font-weight: 700; -> bold
```

Comment: thank you, this means that I need more fonts, correct?

Comment: yes, ofcourse...

Comment: thank you very much. I started CSS only last week and get so much work pushed onto me practically need to learn on the fly - and I have a call with our customer in one hour. haha. thank you!